# Looping up to a value of a totcount counter

Tags: counters, loops

I'm trying to implement a `foreach` loop in LaTeX limited by the value of a `totcount` counter, but this doesn't work at all and I don't understand why.

Can this be done at all, and if yes, how?

Here's a minimal example of failure:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
% dummy totcount counter
\newtotcounter{dummycounter}
\addtocounter{dummycounter}{10}
Total of dummy counter = \total{dummycounter}

% for loop with explicit number
\foreach\index in {1,...,10}{repeat }

% for loop with number taken from totcount counter
\foreach\index in {1,...,\total{dummycounter}}{repeat}

\end{document}
```

The resulting output looks like:

```
Total of dummy counter = 10
repeat repeat repeat repeat repeat repeat repeat repeat repeat repeat
repeat10pt¿1pt10pt
```

and the error message on the console looks like:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.15 ...ex in {1,...,\total{dummycounter}}{repeat}
```

so it appears that in the context of `\foreach`, the output of `\total` is not interpreted as a number. This is very puzzling, as by definition, it is a number.

Clarification of the packages:

- The goal of using `totcount` is to add some values during a first run, which then get written to the `.aux` file and can be used on a second run (I already use it succesfully elsewhere)
- `pgffor` is a possible way to implement loops, as found in answers to other questions in this site; I did try others, without any more success for this particular question, but `pgffor` seems to be simpler to implement in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\total` is not expandable which probably is the problem here. However,

```
\foreach\index in {1,...,\totvalue{dummycounter}}{repeat}
```

works, because `\totvalue` is expandable and expands to a number (which is –1 on the first run) that can be tested.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
% dummy totcount counter
\newtotcounter{dummycounter}
\addtocounter{dummycounter}{10}
Total of dummy counter = \total{dummycounter}

% for loop with explicit number
\foreach\index in {1,...,10}{repeat }

% for loop with number taken from totcount counter
\foreach\index in {1,...,\totvalue{dummycounter}}{repeat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As clemens explained, `\total` is not expandable since it uses an internal `\def`, which prevents expansion -- in the very end, it can't be used in an numerical expansion context which is necessary in the `\if` condition in order to check for the end of a loop.

I also apply `\totvalue` here, but in a traditional `TeX` `\loop`:

Side note: `counters` should be defined preferably in the preamble, not somewhere in the document body.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}


\newcounter{loopcntr}


\newtotcounter{dummycounter}
\begin{document}
\addtocounter{dummycounter}{10}
Total of dummy counter = \total{dummycounter}

\loop\unless\ifnum\value{loopcntr}>\numexpr\totvalue{dummycounter}-1%
\stepcounter{loopcntr}
\theloopcntr\ repeat

\repeat


\end{document}
```

[image]